# Using default datum transformation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

QGIS 3.4: My project uses Pseudo Mercator as the CRS (datum: WGS 1984). I now added a shapefile which uses a local coordinate system from Austria (datum: MGI). I did not define a **datum transformation** in the general QGIS settings, neither did i define a datum transformation in the project settings->CRS (it is empty).

I would expect that no transformation is used and that there is an offset between my map and the shapefile (like in ArcGIS), but the shapefile aligns correctly with my background map (which is Pseudo Mercator, like the project CRS).

**I assume that there is a default transformation, even if I did not define anything, but where can I see the default datum transformation** or how does QGIS deal with that?

Comment: IMO, one of the advantages of QGIS over ArcGIS is that the user doesn't have to worry about datums, only CRS (everyone who ever took a beginner Arc course came away completely confused about projections vs datums). If you want to torture yourself, [this github thread](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/100) has a summary of how QGIS *formerly* handled datum transformations, back in August 2017. Read through all the comments to follow the changes that have been made since then.

Comment: @csk you're still dealing with datums in QGIS--they're part of the geographic CRS (and thus projected CRS too). Anyway, GIS7 does the particular MGI definition you're using include a +wgs84 keyword or +nadgrds? That could also set a transformation.

Comment: thank you for your feedback: @mkennedy: I guess that this is the "standard" transformation (https://epsg.io/1618). I know I could change it, but how can I be sure which transformation has been used by default? It is not visible.

Comment: If you right-click on the layer, then `Set CRS`, `Set Layer CRS`, you see what projection parameters are used. The `+towgs84` parameters indicate the datum transformation.

Comment: thanks AndreJ, now I know how I can find out what is the standard datum transformation! I was right, in my case it was EPSG 1618. (577.326, 90.129, 463.919, 5.137, 1.474, 5.297, 2.4232). It would be a good enhancement if the standard datum transformation would be also visible in the project settings->CRS (where you can set another datum transformation)

Comment: @GIS7 this will be implemented as soon as PROJ v6 can be used by GDAL and QGIS: https://gdalbarn.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment from AndreJ: "If you right-click on the layer, then Set CRS, Set Layer CRS, you see what projection parameters are used. The +towgs84 parameters indicate the datum transformation"